# Error building with Service Now connector v5.0.0 for Mule 3.7.1

Tags: maven, mule, servicenow

I've been trying to do some tests with the new ServiceNow connector and Mule 3.7.1 but when I try to build the project and run it, it fails with the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project xxx: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx:mule:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.modules:mule-module-servicenow:jar:5.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.modules:mule-module-servicenow:jar:5.0.0: Could not transfer artifact org.mule.modules:mule-module-servicenow:pom:5.0.0 from/to mule-ee-releases (https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I believe I have added the correct information into the correct sections in pom.xml

```
                    <inclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-module-servicenow</artifactId>
                    </inclusion>


      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-servicenow</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>



        <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases1</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository-master.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-snapshots1</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository-master.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
```

I had to change the id of the two new repositories, since my pom already had repositories of those id's.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the EE maven credentials set settings.xml? I was able to build an empty application using mule-module-servicenow with the following auto-generated (by dragging the connector from Anypoint pallet onto canvas) repositories:

```
<repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>Central</id>
        <name>Central</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
<repository>
        <id>mule-ee-releases</id>
        <name>MuleEE Releases Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-release</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```